# WebRequest.Create is a wait until process complete code required?

Tags: c#

When using the WebRequest.Create do I have to set a wait/response code before processing the next link. Meaning will WebRequest function auto wait until its complete before processing the next step or another link?

```
try
    {
    req = WebRequest.Create(strURL + listId.SelectedItem as string + "&admire=1");
    req.Proxy = proxyObject;
    req.Method = "POST";
    req.Timeout = 5000;
    }
    catch (Exception eq)
    {
    string sErr = "Cannot connect to " + listId.SelectedItem + " : " + eq.Message;
    MessageBox.Show(sErr, strURL, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
    }
```

Comment: You aren't sending the request at all.

Comment: @SLaks I'm not? can you please assist, this is my first at. I'm learning as I go along.

Comment: To send the request, call `GetResponse()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `GetResponse()` method is a synchronous method that will only return after the server sends a reply.

The `BeginGetResponse()` method is an asynchronous method that will return immediately, before the server replies.

Comment: so i'd do something like this... 
req.Timeout = 5000;
WebResponse reqWebResponse = req.GetResponse();
reqWebResponse.Close();
that would make it submit the url?